# Kotlin combined usage of arrow, lamda, ?, . , and let. what it mean?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun theItemDTO.toDomainModel(
    domainOrderId: String,
    pIds: List<Long> = emptyList()
): theItem = let { dto ->
    OrderProtoBuilders.theItem {
        this.id = dto.id.toString()
        skuId = dto.catalogEntryId.toString()
        orderId = domainOrderId
        quantity = dto.quantity
        unitPrice = dto.unitPrice
        totalPrice = dto.totalPrice
        price = null
        for (pId in pIds)
            addpId(pId.toString())

        dto.someMap[MAP_A]
            ?.let(::setAId)

        dto.someMap[MAP_B]
            ?.let(::setBId)
    }
}
```

For above kotlin function, my order of questions starts from the inner block code to the outter block:
1. what is `dto.someMap[MAP_A]
            ?.let(::setAId)` doing? It looks like a reassignment of `someMap[MAP_A]`, but also a declaration of `let` something... what is it doing?

2. the meaning of so many `{` wrapper is the same as `return`. correct? Since I did read `->` is like a function returning value automatically. So the end value of `...: theItem` is really what `OrderProtoBuilders.theItem {...` created?

```
let { dto ->
    OrderProtoBuilders.theItem {...
```

Comment: `?.` means "only if the object to the left is not null", `let` means "do this code" (the object it's called on is available via `it`), and finally `let { dto -> ... }` sets a custom alias (access the object via `dto`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `dto.someMap[MAP_A]?.let(::setAId)` can be expanded like

```
val value = dto.someMap[MAP_A]
if (value != null) {
    setAId(value)
}
```

2.
Yep, it's correct. You can think about it like

```
//the whole function will return item created by OrderProtoBuilders.theItem
fun theItemDTO.toDomainModel(
    domainOrderId: String,
    pIds: List<Long> = emptyList()
): theItem = let { dto ->
    //return OrderProtoBuilders.theItem
    OrderProtoBuilders.theItem {
        //do some additional initialization of the Item
    }
}
```